# How can I count the number of files in a folder within a JAR?

Tags: java

I've spent a bit of time trying to find a way to count the number of files in a folder within a JAR. I put together several examples of code that served different purposes to make this work. It counts just fine when I run the code through Eclipse but after exporting to a JAR it fails and returns 0. In this case, my folder path I use is just "rules/". I would appreciate any recommendations or samples. Thanks.

```
public static int countFiles(String folderPath) throws IOException { //Counts the number of files in a specified folder
    ClassLoader loader = ToolSet.class.getClassLoader();
    InputStream is = loader.getResourceAsStream(folderPath);
    try {
        byte[] c = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        int readChars = 0;
        boolean empty = true;
        while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
            empty = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                if (c[i] == '\n') {
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }
        return (count == 0 && !empty) ? 1 : count;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The following doesn't exactly match my original question but thanks to MadProgrammer I was able to reduce my code and eliminate the need to even count the files. The code blow searches every file in my JAR looking for those that end with ".rules", opens the file, searches the file for a string that matches "searchBox.getText()", appends results, and continues on to the next ".rules" file.

```
    StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;
    JarFile jf = null;
    try {
        String path = ToolSet.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
        jf = new JarFile(new File(decodedPath));
        Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jf.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            if (entry.getName().endsWith(".rules")) {
                String name = entry.getName();
                InputStream in = ToolSet.class.getResourceAsStream(name);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line;
                while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                    String lowerText = line.toLowerCase();
                    if(lowerText.indexOf(searchBox.getText().toLowerCase()) > 0) {
                        results.append(line + "\n");
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                bf.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        try {
            jf.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
        }
    }
    if(count>0) {
        logBox.setText(results.toString());
    } else {
        logBox.setText("No matches could be found");
    }
```

Comment: Your code works inside Eclipse but when you create an executable JAR file of the code it fails? Correct?

Perhaps you should tell how you create the JAR file and any possible output of that process? Just thinking out loud. :)

Comment: There is probably no good way to do this without actually opening the JAR file itself (directly from your code). Trying to load it through the class loader will not allow listing, and it will also "merge" resources from different sources together. More context why you need this would be helpful.

Comment: since jar is just a zipped file, wouldn't it be easier to read it as such (there are gzip classes just for this) ?

Comment: The program is a set of tools in SWT I use to speed up some daily tasks. I export the class in Eclipse as a runnable JAR file. The rest of the tools work perfect. The reason I have this function is to specify the length of an array. But I also have another variation that loops through each file, reads the file, looks for some matching texts, appends to a string, continues to the next file and repeats. I'm sure there's better ways but this was what I stumbled upon while looking for answers.

Comment: AFAIK `getResource` can't read a directory, in fact Jar/Zip files actually have no concept of directories, other then the entry has a name with path separators...A better solution would be to write a known file into the Jar when it is built with the number (and possibly the name) of the resources are you trying to load

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Jar file is essentially a Zip file with a manifest.

Jar/Zip files don't actually have a concept of directories like disks do.  They simply have a list of entries that have names.  These names may contain some kind path separator and some entries may actually be marked as directories (and tend not to have any bytes associated with them, merely acting as markers)

If you want to find all the resources within a given path, you're going to have to open the Jar file and inspect it's entries yourself, for example...

```
JarFile jf = null;
try {
    String path = "resources";
    jf = new JarFile(new File("dist/ResourceFolderCounter.jar"));
    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jf.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            String name = entry.getName();
            name = name.replace(path + "/", "");
            if (!name.contains("/")) {
                System.out.println(name);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    try {
        jf.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Now, this requires you to know the name of the Jar file you want to use, this may be problematic, as you may wish to list resources from a number of different Jars...

A better solution would be to generate some kind of "resource lookup" file at build time, which contained all the names of the resources that you might need, maybe even keyed to particular names...

This way you could simple use...

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsInputStream("/resources/MasterResourceList.txt")));
    String name = null;
    while ((name = br.readLine()) != null) {
        URL url = getClass().getResource(name);
    }
} finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
}
```

For example...

You could even seed the file with the number of resources ;)

Comment: This did the trick. In fact it greatly reduced my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple solution :

```
InputStream is = loader.getResourceAsStream(folderPath);

//open zip
ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(is);

//count number of files
while ((zip.getNextEntry()) != null ) {
    UnzipCounter++;
}
```