# Read images from resource folder of eclipse without using Image name

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swing

I want to read Images from resource folder of eclipse without using image name. As of now I am reading it from current directory and taking Absolute Path (photoPath) so that I can reproduce the Image in other panel of a JFrame. However if I make executable jar its start taking images from current directory, my image folder is not coming. Here is my Image choosing code

```
    imageChooser = new JButton("ImageChooser");
    panel1.add(imageChooser);
    fc = new JFileChooser();
    imageLabel = new JLabel();
    imageChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
            fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
            int result = fc.showOpenDialog(imageChooser);

            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                currentFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
                imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(currentFile.toString()));
                panel1.add(imageLabel);
                panel1.validate();
                photoName=fc.getSelectedFile().getName();
                photoPath = currentFile.getAbsolutePath();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is my structure

[image]

Comment: It's particularly easy to list the resources embedded within your jar application, it requires you to make so many assumptions about the state of the application.  In these cases, I tend to have a another file, which lists all the resources by name.  I either manually update the file or use some kind of build automation to generate the file.  This means that my entire entry point revolves around a single file instead of needing to make assumptions about where the Jar file is (or which jar file contains the images)

Comment: I am really sorry but couldn't able to understand you !!! If I do getclass(). getResources() I need to specify the image name ,. Can you plz suggest me something?

Comment: So, put the names of the files into a text file, which is also embedded within your application, it should contain a list of the images. Use it to allow you load the images at runtime without needing to know the names. [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758105/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-folder-within-a-jar/18758724#18758724)

Comment: Are you packaging the images in your jar or a separate folder?

Comment: `currentFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
                imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(currentFile.toString()));`  I wish people would actually read the Java Docs for the methods & constructors they use.  If you had on this occasion, you might have noted the `ImageIcon` accepts a `File` as well as a `String`..

Answer (score 1):

use `.getResource()`

Example:

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/button.png"))
```

This will work for JAR as well.

Comment: Hi , but I can't give the file name it has to be dynamic