# Extracting the name of png files from a jar

Tags: java

I have this block of code, which extracts the names of every "png" icon inside a package, I name it "icons".

the code:

```
 Files.walk(Paths.get("src/icons/"), FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS).sorted((e1, e2)
                -> e1.getFileName().compareTo(e2.getFileName())).forEach((Path file) -> {
                    if (!file.getFileName().toString().equals("icons")) {
                        iconcombo.getItems().add(file);
                    }
                });
```

and as I expect, it works:

[image]

the problem is when i use the jar directly i can't reach this files and i get an exception:

[image]

as you can see i used the jar from "dist" directory directly (as it's supposed to be in real user experience) and i run it from the cmd  so you can see the exception.
so any ideas to get the Path object by another method that works inside the jar?

Comment: Your `src` directory won't exist once the program is compiled and packaged.  The files will all be added into the Jar file (which is just basically a fancy zip file), this makes it impossible to reference these resources as any type of file.  While there are some ways to achieve what you're trying to do, they are fragile at best (mostly because you need to know ALL the possible jar files in which the files might exist at runtime). A better solution might be to generate a file which lists all the images and read this at runtime instead.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758105/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-folder-within-a-jar/18758724#18758724).  You could build this list at dynamically at build to make it easier

Comment: you mean for instance, creating a json or xml file in the first launch of the jar, to map the names of the icons ?

Comment: Not on first launch, but when it's built, either manually, creating the file, fill it with the information you want and saving within the projects `src` directly, or by using one of the many build tools, like Ant or Maven, to generate the file dynamically each time you build the project

Comment: thank you that gave me a hint, to what to do next.