# Get folder from Resources folder JAVA

Tags: java, file, src

Hi everyone I can't figure out with this problem : this line of code should work

```
File[] file = (new File(getClass().getResource("resources/images_resultats"))).listFiles();
```

I want a list of File, these Files are under "images_resultats" under "resources".

[image: Project image]

Comment: Resources are not files, in most cases they are entries in a zip container (the jar file) and not be accessed or treated like files. It is very difficult to list the contents of an unknown jar file in this manner

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758105/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-folder-within-a-jar/18758724#18758724), the second solution suggests using a "known" file/resource which contains a list of the resources names, which could be generated at build time

Comment: If the directory is not included in the jar, you should be able to use a relative path directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work if `resources/images_resultats` is not in your classpath and/or if it is in a jar file.

Your code should rather be something like this:

```
File[] file = (new File(getClass().getResource("/my/path").toURI()))
                  .listFiles();
```

Comment: so I must have a folder containing my three folder `images_resultats` etc... and the `.jar`

Comment: To get the relative paths use `list()` instead of `listFiles()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine what files are in a folder in resources (even if its in a jar) using the FileSystem class.

```
public static void doSomethingWithResourcesFolder(String inResourcesPath) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = ResourcesFolderUts.class.getResource(inResourcesPath).toURI();
    try( FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, Collections.emptyMap() ) ){
        Path folderRootPath = fileSystem.getPath(inResourcesPath);
        Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(folderRootPath, 1);
        walk.forEach(childFileOrFolder -> {
            //do something with the childFileOrFolder
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

inResourcesPath should be something like `"/images_resultats"`

Note that the childFileOrFolder paths can only be used while the FileSystem remains open, if you try to (for example) return the paths then use them later you've get a file system closed exception.

Change ResourcesFolderUts for one of your own classes

Answer (score -3):

Assuming that resources folder is in classpath, this might work.

```
   String folder = getClass().getResource("images_resultats").getFile();
   File[] test = new File(folder).listFiles();
```

Comment: it return a `java.lang.NullPointerException` -> `String folder = getClass().getResource("images_resultats").getFile();`

Comment: `getClass().getResource("images_resultats").getFile()` returns null whether folder is empty!