# Count the number of files inside an entry of jar file

Tags: java, jar

I'm searching for a way to count the number of files inside an entry of a jar file.

For example, assume I have inside the jar a folder called "myFolder", I want to be able to count the number of files inside of it.

I used the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758105/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-folder-within-a-jar) to get to myFolder, yet I don't know how to get to the files inside.

Here is my code:

```java
private int countFiles() {
    JarFile jf = null;
    int counter = 0;
    try {
        jf = new JarFile(new File(ClassName.class
                .getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()));
        Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jf.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                if (entry.getName().equals("myFolder/")) {
                    ///////
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        try {
            jf.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: [I use this](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/7-jarsearch) when I want to search across directories and into jars. The 'files' will be in the `else` block (unwritten) of your code.

Comment: Does it have to be in Java? I mean, you can `jar tf | wc -l` from the shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do this in Java then it might be easier to use the *ZIP File System Provider* from the NIO2 API.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path jarFile = Path.of("path", "to", "file.jar");
    String directoryPath = "/myFolder";

    long fileCount = countFilesInDir(jarFile, directoryPath);
    System.out.println(fileCount);
  }

  public static long countFilesInDir(Path jarFile, String directory) throws IOException {
    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jarFile)) {
      return Files.list(fs.getPath(directory)).count();
    }
  }
}
```

If you only want to count *regular files* then change:

```java
return Files.list(fs.getPath(directory)).count();
```

To:

```java
return Files.list(directory).filter(Files::isRegularFile).count();
```

And if you want to count the entries/files *recursively* then check out the `java.nio.file.Files#find(Path,int,BiPredicate,FileVisitOption...)` method.

---

**Note**: Normally you should close the `Stream` returned by `Files.list` or `Files.find` when done with it, but in this case it should be closed as a consequence of the `FileSystem` being closed.

Answer (score 1):

Only empty directories in the jar will pass the `isDirectory` test.
For file entries, directory will be contained in the name

```
shell> import java.util.jar.JarFile;

JarFile jf = new JarFile(new File("test.jar"));
jf ==> java.util.jar.JarFile@32d992b2

jf.stream().forEach(f -> System.out.println(f.getName()))
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
dir1/Order.MOVED
dir1/Pet.MOVED
dir1/Tag.MOVED
dir1/User.MOVED
empty/

jf.stream().forEach(f -> { if(f.getName().contains("dir1/")) System.out.println(f.getName()) ;})
dir1/Order.MOVED
dir1/Pet.MOVED
dir1/Tag.MOVED
dir1/User.MOVED
jf.stream().forEach(f -> { if(f.getName().contains("dir1/dir2/")) System.out.println(f.getName()) ;})
dir1/dir2/
dir1/dir2/Pet.MOVED
dir1/dir2/Order.MOVED
```

Can be used without checking if it's a directory as

```
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
    JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
    if (entry.getName().contains("myFolder/")) {
        ///////
    }
}
```

This should also work

```
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
    JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
    if (!entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().startsWith("myFolder/")) {
        ///////
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being a newbie, but how do I use it? I'm quite new to java.

Comment: np :-) Added how to the answer.

Comment: and where should I put the first code block? I puted it inside the 'if', but it is probably not the right place because i'm getting errors. thanks again :)

Comment: Use one of the `while...` blocks